# C# - EF core one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm new and I hope you can help me figure this out, thanks in advice to everyone.
Let's say I've got these 3 models

```
public class Especialidad
{
    public int IdEspecialidad { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public List<MedicoEspecialidad> MedicoEspecialidad { get; set; }
}

public class Medico
{
    public int IdMedico { get; set; }

    public List<MedicoEspecialidad> MedicoEspecialidad { get; set; }
}

public class MedicoEspecialidad
{
    public int IdMedico { get; set; }
    public int IdEspecialidad { get; set; }

    public Medico Medico { get; set; }
    public Especialidad Especialidad { get; set; }
}
```

and I configured the relationships as following:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MedicoEspecialidad>().HasKey(x => new {x.IdMedico, x.IdEspecialidad});

        modelBuilder.Entity<MedicoEspecialidad>().HasOne(x => x.Medico)
        .WithMany(p => p.MedicoEspecialidad)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdMedico);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MedicoEspecialidad>().HasOne(x => x.Especialidad)
        .WithMany(p => p.MedicoEspecialidad)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdEspecialidad);
```

The problem that I've got is that when I delete Especialidad I can't edit/delete Medico cause it has no Especialidad and it's trying to Remove the relationship. And also it's not possible to delete Especialidad without having it assigned to a Medico because it's trying to delete the relationship and it's not found.

this is the Delete method in EspecialidadController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var medicoEspecialidad = await _context.MedicoEspecialidad
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(me => me.IdEspecialidad == id);

        _context.MedicoEspecialidad.Remove(medicoEspecialidad);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var especialidad = await _context.Especialidad.FindAsync(id);

        _context.Especialidad.Remove(especialidad);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

this is the delete method in MedicoController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var medicoEspecialidad = await _context.MedicoEspecialidad
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(me => me.IdMedico == id);

        _context.MedicoEspecialidad.Remove(medicoEspecialidad);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var medico = await _context.Medico.FindAsync(id);

        _context.Medico.Remove(medico);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

this is the Edit method in MedicoController

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("IdMedico,Nombre,Apellido,Direccion,Telefono,Email,HorarioAtencionDesde,HorarioAtencionHasta")] Medico medico, int IdEspecialidad)
    {
        if (id != medico.IdMedico)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(medico);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                var medicoEspecialidad = await _context.MedicoEspecialidad
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(me => me.IdMedico == id);

                _context.Remove(medicoEspecialidad);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


                medicoEspecialidad.IdEspecialidad = IdEspecialidad;

                _context.Add(medicoEspecialidad);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

Comment: you are creating many-to-many relationship between Especialidad and Medico in a indirect way. if you wanna delete row which is relates to those tables, u have to delete it first in MedicoEspecialidad table.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I am actually deleting it first in the MedicoEspecialidad table as you can see in the methods. The problem starts for example when I delete a Especialidad, it actually works, but now if I want to delete a Medico, it's not possible because the IdEspecialidad in MedicoEspecialidad table is empty and in the Delete method in MedicoController i'm trying to delete it but it can't find it.. I'm sorry if it's confusing

Comment: in the delete method and in the part of that ```var medicoEspecialidad = await _context.MedicoEspecialidad
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(me => me.IdMedico == id);```code block, you are calling the data that you gonna delete but there can be more values for that ```IdMedico``` key because there is a two primary key in  that ```MedicoEspecialidad``` table. to block that you have to call your data with ```IdMedico``` and ```IdEspecialidad``` keys and then delete that data. I think this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the record from m-m MedicoEspecialidad table and from main table in one transaction, so use   SaveChanges only ones. And you will have to check if a MedicoEspecialidad table has a record before trying to remove from this table

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var medicoEspecialidad = await _context.MedicoEspecialidad
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(me => me.IdEspecialidad == id);

        if ( medicoEspecialidad != null)
        _context.MedicoEspecialidad.Remove(medicoEspecialidad);
       
        var especialidad = await _context.Especialidad.FindAsync(id);
       var result=0;
       if (especialidad !=null)
       {
        _context.Especialidad.Remove(especialidad);
        result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        if (result > 0) return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        return null; // or better to return an error message
    }
```

the same logic is for another table Medico

Comment: I solved it, i'll post how I did later. thanks BerkGarip and Serge!